# Preventing an Instance Method from Printing to Console

Tags: ruby, mysql2, puts

I am writing a simple Ruby script that utilizes the `mysql2` gem.

In order to properly terminate a connection with the database and avoid the `Too many connections` error, I store my connection into the variable `mysql` like so:

```
mysql = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => hst, :username => usr, :password => pass, :database => db, :connect_timeout => 30)
```

and then I close the connection:

```
mysql.close
```

When this occurs, I get:

```
closed MySQL connection
```

in the console.

How can I implement the Instance Method `#close` found [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.3.13/Mysql2/Client#close-instance_method) without `closed MySQL connection` showing up in the terminal?

Comment: `closed MySQL connection` is actually an error message. Are you executing any queries after closing the connection?

Comment: @stefan It's a loop that will `retry` until the `db` is accessible.  What does the `closed MySQL connection` error mean then?

Comment: It means that you are attempting to run a query with a closed connection, e.g. `mysql.close; mysql.query(...)`

Comment: @stefan You're 100% right.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this:

```
def silence_stdout
  $stdout = File.new( '/dev/null', 'w' )
  yield
  ensure
  $stdout = STDOUT
end
```

and do the `close`  with that method

```
silence_stdout{mysql.close}
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thank you for the solution.